# Temporarily disable SElinux

Tags: centos, selinux

I want to temporarily disable SELinux on Centos 7. However, `setenforce Permissive` has no effect.

```
# setenforce Permissive
# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

Comment: `sestatus` says SELinux is set to permissive, which means SELinux rules are not enforced, only logged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot disable SELinux without rebooting.

You can set it to Permissive mode at runtime via

```
setenforce Permissive
```

or

```
setenforce 0
```

In this mode, SELinux behaves like it's disabled; thatis, it does not enforce rules, but just logs any violations of them (in the file `/var/log/avc.log`, `/var/log/audit/audit.log`, or `/var/log/audit.log`, depending on which services are running on your machine).